# Are there any guidelines for appropriate use of the Black HUD UI in OS X?

Tags: macos, hud, hig

Does anyone know what the HIG are saying about the black HUD UI in OS X?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

See [the Transparent Panels section of Apple's Human Interface Guidelines](http://developer.apple.com/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/AppleHIGuidelines/XHIGWindows/XHIGWindows.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000961-SW24).

Comment: best. conversation. ever. "What does document X say about Y?" "Read document X."

Comment: LOL... I figured he was looking for the relevant section of the HIG (a HUGE document).

Comment: HUGE - but searchable (I was only referring to it yesterday) ;-)

Answer (score 1):

Basically HIG say that black HUD UI is named a transparent panel.

Its role is the same as a standard panel, i.e., an auxiliary window that offers some controls related to the current document.

Its look is as discrete as possible, in particular in highly visual applications.